# How do I permanently turn off Google Instant in Google Chrome 17?

Tags: google-chrome

I already know how to adjust the settings in https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en.

It's just that it keeps on reverting the settings - which it didn't do in any previous version of Chrome...

Even when I'm logged onto my Gmail account, it doesn't revert itself in Firefox...

Also, I did enable Cookies as mentioned at 
http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=61416

Comment: I do not have this problem. If you use the integrated sync, maybe try a complete uninstall + wipe, then when you re-install let it sync but don't sync the settings down from the server?

Comment: Hm interesting - what sorts of problems does the integrated sync cause?

Comment: None as far as I am aware, and I successfully fixed installations that way before, by syncing only my Bookmarks + Addons + Apps and such onto the server, and then completely purging Chrome, doing a re-install, and fetching my synced data again. As far as I know the data is put onto Google's servers fully encrypted, so at least in theory they should not have any access.